# How can I play multiple characters at once?

Tags: player-characters, warcraft-rpg

Okay, so I'll be playing the World of Warcraft RPG with my family and friends on the weekend, and I'm wondering if playing multiple characters at once would be viable or easy to do.

I'll be playing as a Goblin Tinker, and I'm thinking about adding a second Goblin to go along with him, think like Techies from DotA, so they'd probably be one 'unit' when attack turns come around, they fight as one.

Would this work at all? And how would I go about playing them?

Comment: Related: Same question for 4e - [How can you create one PC that is more than one "person"?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61750)

Comment: Is this the PC game, or a tabletop game?

Comment: @gomad For reference: [World of Warcraft: The Roleplaying Game](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/915/world-warcraft-roleplaying-game).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - yes, I know. But it's a 1st question from a new user and an easy mistake to make. Thought it was worth clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Playing multiple characters is certainly viable: you simply make two separate characters and play them both. They are then no different than any other two characters, except that they're controlled by the same player. (You need to clear the whole idea with your GM first though, else it becomes distinctly un-viable.)

To make them work together you just decide their actions so that they work together, rather than altering the rules for actions.

There are pitfalls to be aware of, of course. Two in particular are [how to handle knowledge one PC has that the other doesn't](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62994/how-can-i-avoid-metagaming-when-i-know-things-my-character-doesnt); and the fact that the other players may object to you getting twice as much character as they do.